# How to do bandwidth control for download request from Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, scalability

I have a tomcat server which will be located at Amazon EC2 instance.
It will serve files download request from about 10000 clients.

```
Each client will follow the steps to download some files:
(1) Send request to Tomcat to check if need to update files
(2) Tomcat will send the file list to client if any
(3) Client will download the file list via HTTP servlet.
```

Basically we want to achieve the goal when Tomcat server is high-loaded(due to bandwidth/session limit etc),Tomcat will return one INTERVAL to client request, 
then the client will wait INTERVAL time to re-send the download request.
Is there any good way to design for such scenery?

Comment: Do you have control over the clients? For example, are you providing the client software to your users?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the HTTP Cache control and Range headers to help manage this. That's pretty much dead on for what you want to do.

If you're working with static files (i.e. files that Tomcat will serve directly itself vs some dynamic content generated through a Servlet or other such thing), then Tomcat will honor the Range headers for you automatically.

The game there is that your client will have to make HTTP requests that actually use the Range headers, and the client will have to be the one to throttle the connection.

If your client is willing to take that responsibility, then stock out of the box Tomcat should work just fine, simply publish a file system directory via the server. Out of the box it will show a listing of the files in the directory, and then you can use the Caching headers to determine what has changed, and the Range headers to parcel out the content.

Comment: If the clients cannot be controlled, you might consider putting Apache httpd in front of Tomcat and using mod_qos to perform traffic-shaping to, for instance, limit the bandwidth used by any particular client.

Comment: @ Christopher Schultz, i can not control the client. It is developed by another department, although in same company.

Comment: @ Will Hartung, i can not control the client behavior. And the files is dynamically generated through Servlet. We get the files from Amazon S3 and put in memory as byte[], which will be returned to client via Servlet OutputStream.